# react-bootstrap-sweetalert alert is not coming on the center of screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a sweet alert popup on my screen, when I click the button it shows but on the bottom right corner of the screen. I want it in the center of div it contains. I've tried to make it inside the bootstrap grid and center it. But it doesn't seem to work. Here's the screenshot.
[image]
Here's my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Row, Col, Grid } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showAlert:null,
        }
    }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.alertShow()}>Click Me!</button>
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col md="4"></Col>
                <Col md="4">
                {this.state.showAlert}
                </Col>
                <Col md="4"></Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    </div>
    );
  }

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
        showAlert: null
    });
}
alertShow = () => {
    this.setState({
        showAlert: <SweetAlert
        warning
       showCancel
       confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
       confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
       cancelBtnBsStyle="success"
       title={"Are you sure to delete ?"}
       onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
       onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
       focusCancelBtn
   >
       Message details also will be deleted!
  </SweetAlert>
    });
}
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Try move `{this.state.showAlert}` under your `div`

Comment: Like immediately after `<div>`, right? I've tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this problem. I manually set the style property of `<SweetAlert>` to center the element.

Here's my updated code for `<SweetAlert>`.

```
<SweetAlert
        warning
        showCancel
        confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
        confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
        cancelBtnBsStyle="success"
        title={"Are you sure to delete ?"}
        onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
        onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
        focusCancelBtn
        style={{right:"0",left:"0",top:"0",bottom:"0",marginRight:"auto",marginLeft:"auto",marginTop:"auto",marginBottom:"auto"}}
    >
        Message details also will be deleted!
</SweetAlert>
```

Thanks!